# How to reflect a number output in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a programm which draws a picture from numbers in certain way

```
n = int(input(" Введіть ваше число "))
m = n * 2 - 1
pp = " "
i = 0
while m != 0:
    l = []
    while m > n:
        while i < n:
            i += 1
            j = n - i
            k = i
            while j != 0:
                l.append(pp)
                j -= 1
            while k != 0:
                l.append(str(k))
                k -= 1
        m -= 1
        a = " "
        print(a.join(l))
        l = []
i = 0
```

OUTPUT:

```
         1
       2 1
     3 2 1
   4 3 2 1
 5 4 3 2 1
```

But now I get a task to draw this picture

```
1
1 2 
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there any hint how to reflect it without overwriting the whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the output you are expecting, a very simple way to do it is with this code :

```
n = 5
for i in range(n):
  print(' '.join([str(x+1) for x in range(i+1)]))
```

Output :

```
1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: ty a lot, it works, but with a little problem. PyCharm makes big spaces between strings in output

Comment: remove the line `print("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Its simple.

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
for j in range(1, i+1):
    print(j, end="")
print()
```

Comment: That is great @JaneMiller